# Passing a struct by reference instead of value within void functions

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures

I am trying to create a contact list using structures and functions. Currently my code compiles but the members of the struct are not being modified outside of the function like I am trying to do. Here is my code(removed some lines for length)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct ContactInfo
{
    char fname[50];
    char lname[50];
};

struct ContactInfo gc;

void getContactInfo(struct ContactInfo gc)
{
    printf("First Name: ");
    scanf("%s", gc.fname);

    printf("\nLast Name: ");
    scanf("%s", gc.lname);
}

void showContactInfo(struct ContactInfo gc)
{
    printf("* First Name: %s \n", gc.fname);

    printf("* Last Name: %s \n", gc.lname);
}

int main()
{
    getContactInfo(gc);

    showContactInfo(gc);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're passing by value.  By ref is foo&  (notice the "&") in the declaration.

Comment: @DaveS C doesn't have references.

Comment: melpomene is correct. If you wanted to use 'references' you'd have to make the function void func(struct type * s), then pass it your struct using &, to pass it the pointer

Comment: `scanf` `%s` is fundamentally unsafe (you're reading unlimited input into a fixed-size buffer). Also, using `scanf` for user input is a bad idea in general. Consider using `fgets` instead.

Comment: The fact that the functions don't return anything does not bear directly on the problem.

Comment: @melpomene - d'oh!  It's been a few years since I've worked with "real" C instead of C code compiled in C++.  I assumed the question made sense in newer versions of C  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `getContactInfo`, you need to pass a pointer to the struct:

```
void getContactInfo( struct ContactInfo *gcptr )
{
  printf("First Name: ");
  scanf("%s", gcptr->fname);

  printf("\nLast Name: ");
  scanf("%s", gcptr->lname);
}
```

Since you're trying to modify the contents `gc`, you need to pass a pointer to it to the function.  Remember that C passes all arguments by value, so the called function creates a separate, duplicate object that receives the value of the parameter.  Your code is modifying that duplicate object, which has no effect on the actual parameter.

The `->` operator is used when the operand is a pointer to a `struct` or `union` type - it implicitly dereferences the pointer before accessing the particular member.  It's equivalent to writing `(*gcptr).fname` and `(*gcptr).lname`, while being a little easier on the eyes.

You'd call this function as

```
getContactInfo( &gc );
```

For `showContactInfo`, you can leave it as it is since you're not trying to modify the parameter.  However, a lot of people like to pass pointers to `struct`s to save memory (you're not building a copy of the `struct` in the called function).  If you want to use a pointer, I would recommend using the `const` keyword like so:

```
void showContactInfo( const struct ContactInfo *gcptr )
{
  printf("* First Name: %s \n", gcptr->fname);
  printf("* Last Name: %s \n", gcptr->lname);
}
```

The `const` keyword tells the compiler to yell at me if I try to modify the contents of the object `gcptr` points to in the `showContactInfo` function.  Like `getContactInfo` above, you'd call it as

```
showContactInfo( &gc );
```

Note that I changed the argument names to `gcptr` just to help distinguish between the formal argument in the function definition and the actual argument in the function call.  I normally don't like putting any kind of type information in a variable or argument name, but you can use whatever naming convention you like.

Answer (score 1):

The C way for doing this is just plain old pointers:

```
void showContactInfo(struct ContactInfo* gc)
{
    printf("* First Name: %s \n", gc->fname);

    printf("* Last Name: %s \n", gc->lname);
}
```

Other than having to use the arrow operator `->` to access properties it's basically the same.

C itself does not have references like C++ does.

Comment: More importantly, a similar change needs to be made in **get**ContactInfo().

Comment: Indeed, the primary reason to make that change to **show**ContactInfo() is for consistency.  It already works as it is, because it's not trying to modify the structure.

Comment: Thank you guys.  I made the changes.  I def need to understand pointers.This may sound like a dumb question. How would I call the functions in main now?

Answer (score 1):

The `getContactInfo` function is supposed to return values, but you pass values in instead.

The most natural  way to get data out of a function is to use the return value. Also you should not use global variables for passing data.  The code could look like:

```
struct ContactInfo getContactInfo(void)
{
    struct ContactInfo g = { 0 };  // ensure no garbage in case input fails

    printf("First Name: ");
    scanf("%49s", g.fname);

    printf("Last Name: ");
    scanf("%49s", g.lname);

    return g;
}
```

with the code in `main` being:

```
struct ContactInfo gc = getContactInfo();
showContactInfo(gc);
```

Comment: This approach requires allocating 2 structs and copying between them, which is fine if it's only done once but it would be faster and use only one allocation (and no copying) to either pass a pointer, or to have the function malloc the struct and return a pointer.

Comment: @DaveS Please post a benchmark showing the alleged speed difference.  A stack allocation is a single instruction so it would be interesting if you can measure this. Also I doubt there is a copy associated with the return value (e.g. x64 ABI in fact mandates that there is not a copy). My guess would be that `malloc` is orders of magnitude slower than this.

Comment: The `showContactInfo` could perhaps be hand-optimized to pass by pointer

Comment: You're correct for this example.  Sorry if my comment was too brief to be clear.  I meant in general, not for this specific simple case.  In general alloc-create-alloc-copy is going to be worse than just alloc-create especially for larger more complicated structs and such structs might not even fit comfortably on the stack.